# Not able to read the values from ‘App.config’ file in the Unit testing project (Nunit)

Tags: c#, selenium, frameworks, dependencies, nunit

I have created one ‘nunit’ project in a visual studio which contains a simple one test. There is no default ‘App.config’ file available, so I have created one ‘App.config’ file. I have marked this file ‘Copy always’ from its ‘properties’ option.

I have tried to read the values from 'config' file is two ways 'ConfigurationManager.AppSettings' and 'system.configuration.configurationmanager.AppSettings'. but, It is showing empty values (null values)

Please see my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using log4net;
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnitTestProject1.Config;
using NUnitTestProject1.Helper;

namespace NUnitTestProject1.AutomationTest
{
   [TestFixture, Order(3)]
    public class ReadDataThoughExcel
    {

        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

       [Test, Order(1)]
        public void IsUserReadDataThroughExcel() {

    string data1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"];
    Console.Write("Print data "+data1);
    string data2 = system.configuration.configurationmanager.AppSettings["name"];
    Console.Write("Print data "+data2);
  }
 }
}

like so
```

Config file code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <ApplicationSettings>
        <add key="name" value="Configuration Example Project"/>
    </ApplicationSettings>
</configuration>

like so
```

**Configuration details of my project:**

1. **Dot.Net Framework:** Microsoft.NET Framework version 4.7.0
2. **OS:** window 10
3. **IDE:** Visual studio 2019
4. Use **Nunit framework** for unit testing
5. **NUnit3TestAdapter** (Version) 3.17.0
6. **Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk** (Version) 16.5.0
7. **System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager** (Version) 4.7.0
8. **Selenium.Support** (Version) 3.141.0

**Note:** Also, I have tried to add the reference of the ‘system.configuration’ to my project by right clicking on the 'Dependency' option (showing inside the project name in visual studio), however I am not able to see the option ‘system.configuration’ in the 'Type Libraries' option.

Answer (score 1):

The application you are testing may already have a config file. In addition, NUnit itself may have it's own config file. To avoid conflicts, NUnit has always required the config file used for the **tests** to be named specially.

Specifically, If the assembly containing your tests is named `mytests.dll`, then NUnit will be looking for a config named `mytests.config` in your bin directory.

For details, see my blog post at http://charliepoole.org/technical/how-nunit-finds-config-files.html. [It's unusual for such an old post to remain useful, but in this case, nothing has changed in how NUnit works.]